# Postgresql chooses the wrong index when multiple indexes exist that could satisfy the query

Tags: postgresql

Postgres seems to select the wrong index when one is created for both the were and the order by statement. We can't just alter the indexes per query, because sometimes the where condition is not there from the ORM (Django) in this case. Without it performance would be extremely poor in that case.

**psql (PostgreSQL) 11.5**

```
helium_shopping=# \d products_amalgamateddisplayproduct;
                                                      Table "public.products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"
                  Column                  |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                            Default                             
------------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 id                                       | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_id_seq'::regclass)
 name                                     | character varying(255)   |           | not null | 
 sub_title                                | character varying(255)   |           |          | 
 date_created                             | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 date_updated                             | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 tags                                     | character varying(255)   |           |          | 
 variants                                 | smallint                 |           | not null | 
 rating                                   | numeric(3,2)             |           | not null | 
 reviews                                  | smallint                 |           | not null | 
 is_toppick                               | boolean                  |           | not null | 
 location_intspace                        | integer                  |           | not null | 
 price                                    | numeric(16,2)            |           | not null | 
 quantity                                 | smallint                 |           | not null | 
 department                               | character varying(64)    |           |          | 
 aisle                                    | character varying(64)    |           |          | 
 original_price                           | numeric(16,2)            |           |          | 
 is_onsale                                | boolean                  |           | not null | 
 is_instock                               | boolean                  |           | not null | 
 sale_until                               | date                     |           |          | 
 sale_percent                             | numeric(5,2)             |           | not null | 
 sale_amount                              | numeric(16,2)            |           | not null | 
 orig_display_product_date_created        | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 orig_display_product_access_date_created | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 brand_id                                 | integer                  |           |          | 
 location_id                              | integer                  |           | not null | 
 orig_access_id                           | integer                  |           | not null | 
 orig_product_id                          | integer                  |           | not null | 
 placement_id                             | integer                  |           | not null | 
 poster_image_id                          | integer                  |           |          | 
 retailer_id                              | integer                  |           | not null | 
 variant_id                               | integer                  |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "products_adp_order_2" btree (orig_display_product_date_created DESC, orig_product_id DESC)
    "products_adp_where_1" btree (location_id, placement_id)
    "products_amalgamateddispla_orig_display_product_acces_a379ca16" btree (orig_display_product_access_date_created)
    "products_amalgamateddispla_orig_display_product_date__2aa4f692" btree (orig_display_product_date_created)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_brand_id_1523070a" btree (brand_id)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_is_instock_7197b590" btree (is_instock)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_is_onsale_aa012b24" btree (is_onsale)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_is_toppick_7c861684" btree (is_toppick)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_location_id_eef9319e" btree (location_id)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_orig_access_id_71d2c6fa" btree (orig_access_id)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_orig_product_id_df68bcd8" btree (orig_product_id)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_original_price_847eaae1" btree (original_price)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_placement_id_3d28505e" btree (placement_id)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_poster_image_id_81483fd6" btree (poster_image_id)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_price_b9385183" btree (price)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_quantity_c84abc7d" btree (quantity)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_rating_9fe03e9e" btree (rating)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_retailer_id_af97737a" btree (retailer_id)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_reviews_d19684cc" btree (reviews)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_sale_amount_454287e4" btree (sale_amount)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_sale_percent_23c56bcd" btree (sale_percent)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_sale_until_46bb38df" btree (sale_until)
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct_variant_id_1dafa705" btree (variant_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "products_amalgamated_brand_id_1523070a_fk_products_" FOREIGN KEY (brand_id) REFERENCES products_displaybrand(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "products_amalgamated_location_id_eef9319e_fk_retailers" FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES retailers_baselocation(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "products_amalgamated_orig_access_id_71d2c6fa_fk_products_" FOREIGN KEY (orig_access_id) REFERENCES products_displayproductaccess(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "products_amalgamated_orig_product_id_df68bcd8_fk_products_" FOREIGN KEY (orig_product_id) REFERENCES products_displayproduct(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "products_amalgamated_placement_id_3d28505e_fk_retailers" FOREIGN KEY (placement_id) REFERENCES retailers_displaysubcategory(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "products_amalgamated_poster_image_id_81483fd6_fk_products_" FOREIGN KEY (poster_image_id) REFERENCES products_displayproductimage(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "products_amalgamated_retailer_id_af97737a_fk_retailers" FOREIGN KEY (retailer_id) REFERENCES retailers_retailer(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "products_amalgamated_variant_id_1dafa705_fk_products_" FOREIGN KEY (variant_id) REFERENCES products_displayproductvariant(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

The two (questionable) indexes with Django:

```
CREATE INDEX products_adp_where_1
    ON public.products_amalgamateddisplayproduct USING btree
    (location_id ASC NULLS LAST, placement_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX products_adp_order_2
    ON public.products_amalgamateddisplayproduct USING btree
    (orig_display_product_date_created DESC NULLS FIRST, orig_product_id DESC NULLS FIRST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

With both indexes created (I disabled parallel workers:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT ON (
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."orig_display_product_date_created", 
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."orig_product_id"
  ) "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."id", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."name", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."sub_title", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."date_created", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."date_updated", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."tags", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."variants", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."placement_id", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."poster_image_id", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."brand_id", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."rating", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."reviews", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."is_toppick", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."variant_id", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."retailer_id", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."location_id", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."location_intspace", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."price", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."quantity", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."department", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."aisle", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."original_price", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."is_onsale", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."is_instock", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."sale_until", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."sale_percent", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."sale_amount", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."orig_display_product_date_created", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."orig_display_product_access_date_created", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."orig_product_id", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."orig_access_id" 
FROM 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct" 
WHERE 
  (
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."location_id" IN (
      608, 65, 610, 69, 999, 72, 92, 79, 81, 84, 
      1045, 89, 601, 954, 603, 1276, 605, 607
    ) 
    AND "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."placement_id" IN (
      512, 
      1, 
      516, 
      5, 
      9, 
      12, 
      525, 
      526, 
      1279, 
      1042, 
      21, 
      22, 
      23, 
      26, 
      517, 
      34, 
      35, 
      36, 
      38, 
      39, 
      555, 
      556, 
      46, 
      68, 
      589, 
      597, 
      598, 
      599, 
      600, 
      92, 
      93, 
      95, 
      96, 
      97, 
      98, 
      99, 
      103, 
      104, 
      111, 
      625, 
      629, 
      630, 
      124, 
      126, 
      127, 
      128, 
      129, 
      130, 
      131, 
      133, 
      134, 
      136, 
      649, 
      138, 
      139, 
      533, 
      141, 
      142, 
      143, 
      144, 
      145, 
      150, 
      152, 
      665, 
      666, 
      623, 
      668, 
      538, 
      670, 
      671, 
      672, 
      673, 
      674, 
      163, 
      677, 
      173, 
      1280, 
      693, 
      694, 
      695, 
      696, 
      190, 
      704, 
      195, 
      196, 
      199, 
      206, 
      209, 
      222, 
      739, 
      743, 
      744, 
      233, 
      234, 
      236, 
      752, 
      1272, 
      249, 
      1274, 
      1275, 
      252, 
      765, 
      254, 
      255, 
      768, 
      1281, 
      258, 
      259, 
      260, 
      261, 
      774, 
      641, 
      1293, 
      270, 
      271, 
      272, 
      274, 
      787, 
      1301, 
      790, 
      791, 
      283, 
      1318, 
      809, 
      810, 
      811, 
      813, 
      814, 
      815, 
      306, 
      308, 
      309, 
      1336, 
      1338, 
      318, 
      319, 
      321, 
      834, 
      651, 
      836, 
      838, 
      844, 
      845, 
      846, 
      653, 
      336, 
      1370, 
      350, 
      357, 
      358, 
      882, 
      372, 
      885, 
      889, 
      890, 
      379, 
      380, 
      1258, 
      1412, 
      1343, 
      835, 
      1429, 
      1430, 
      1431, 
      891, 
      413, 
      414, 
      415, 
      1441, 
      667, 
      422, 
      427, 
      669, 
      446, 
      452, 
      453, 
      454, 
      455, 
      459, 
      460, 
      462, 
      463, 
      1443, 
      1273, 
      847, 
      1504, 
      1276, 
      491, 
      1277, 
      1278, 
      766, 
      503, 
      506, 
      767, 
      510
    )
  ) 
ORDER BY 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."orig_display_product_date_created" DESC NULLS FIRST, 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."orig_product_id" DESC NULLS FIRST 
LIMIT 
  51
```

Results with both (685ms):

```
 Limit  (cost=1000.45..2358.91 rows=51 width=812) (actual time=667.727..684.891 rows=51 loops=1)
   ->  Unique  (cost=1000.45..457335.19 rows=17132 width=812) (actual time=667.724..684.798 rows=51 loops=1)
         ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.45..457247.27 rows=17585 width=812) (actual time=667.721..684.826 rows=433 loops=1)
               Workers Planned: 2
               Workers Launched: 0
               ->  Parallel Index Scan using products_adp_order_2 on products_amalgamateddisplayproduct  (cost=0.43..454217.50 rows=7327 width=812) (actual time=667.100..
684.097 rows=433 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((location_id = ANY ('{608,65,610,69,999,72,92,79,81,84,1045,89,601,954,603,1276,605,607}'::integer[])) AND (placement_id = ANY ('{512,1,516,
5,9,12,525,526,1279,1042,21,22,23,26,517,34,35,36,38,39,555,556,46,68,589,597,598,599,600,92,93,95,96,97,98,99,103,104,111,625,629,630,124,126,127,128,129,130,131,133,134
,136,649,138,139,533,141,142,143,144,145,150,152,665,666,623,668,538,670,671,672,673,674,163,677,173,1280,693,694,695,696,190,704,195,196,199,206,209,222,739,743,744,233,
234,236,752,1272,249,1274,1275,252,765,254,255,768,1281,258,259,260,261,774,641,1293,270,271,272,274,787,1301,790,791,283,1318,809,810,811,813,814,815,306,308,309,1336,13
38,318,319,321,834,651,836,838,844,845,846,653,336,1370,350,357,358,882,372,885,889,890,379,380,1258,1412,1343,835,1429,1430,1431,891,413,414,415,1441,667,422,427,669,446
,452,453,454,455,459,460,462,463,1443,1273,847,1504,1276,491,1277,1278,766,503,506,767,510}'::integer[])))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1800287
 Planning Time: 2.650 ms
 Execution Time: 685.116 ms
(10 rows)
```

Now with the second index (products_adp_order_1) dropped:

```
Limit  (cost=29126.93..29127.32 rows=51 width=812) (actual time=16.071..16.198 rows=51 loops=1)
   ->  Unique  (cost=29126.93..29258.82 rows=17132 width=812) (actual time=16.070..16.193 rows=51 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=29126.93..29170.89 rows=17585 width=812) (actual time=16.069..16.087 rows=433 loops=1)
               Sort Key: orig_display_product_date_created DESC, orig_product_id DESC
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 692kB
               ->  Index Scan using products_adp_where_1 on products_amalgamateddisplayproduct  (cost=0.43..24098.61 rows=17585 width=812) (actual time=0.209..13.305 rows
=2240 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((location_id = ANY ('{608,65,610,69,999,72,92,79,81,84,1045,89,601,954,603,1276,605,607}'::integer[])) AND (placement_id = ANY ('{512,1,
516,5,9,12,525,526,1279,1042,21,22,23,26,517,34,35,36,38,39,555,556,46,68,589,597,598,599,600,92,93,95,96,97,98,99,103,104,111,625,629,630,124,126,127,128,129,130,131,133
,134,136,649,138,139,533,141,142,143,144,145,150,152,665,666,623,668,538,670,671,672,673,674,163,677,173,1280,693,694,695,696,190,704,195,196,199,206,209,222,739,743,744,
233,234,236,752,1272,249,1274,1275,252,765,254,255,768,1281,258,259,260,261,774,641,1293,270,271,272,274,787,1301,790,791,283,1318,809,810,811,813,814,815,306,308,309,133
6,1338,318,319,321,834,651,836,838,844,845,846,653,336,1370,350,357,358,882,372,885,889,890,379,380,1258,1412,1343,835,1429,1430,1431,891,413,414,415,1441,667,422,427,669
,446,452,453,454,455,459,460,462,463,1443,1273,847,1504,1276,491,1277,1278,766,503,506,767,510}'::integer[])))
 Planning Time: 0.853 ms
 Execution Time: 16.352 ms
(9 rows)
```

Now another query where that second order by index is very useful.

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT ON (
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."is_instock", 
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."price", 
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."orig_product_id"
  ) "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."id", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."name", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."sub_title", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."date_created", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."date_updated", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."tags", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."variants", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."placement_id", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."poster_image_id", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."brand_id", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."rating", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."reviews", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."is_toppick", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."variant_id", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."retailer_id", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."location_id", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."location_intspace", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."price", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."quantity", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."department", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."aisle", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."original_price", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."is_onsale", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."is_instock", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."sale_until", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."sale_percent", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."sale_amount", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."orig_display_product_date_created", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."orig_display_product_access_date_created", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."orig_product_id", 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."orig_access_id" 
FROM 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct" 
WHERE 
  (
    "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."location_intspace" IN (755) 
    AND "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."location_id" IN (
      608, 65, 610, 69, 999, 72, 92, 79, 81, 84, 
      1045, 89, 601, 954, 603, 1276, 605, 607
    ) 
    AND "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."placement_id" IN (
          512, 
          1, 
          516, 
          5, 
          9, 
          12, 
          525, 
          526, 
          1042, 
          21, 
          22, 
          23, 
          26, 
          517, 
          34, 
          35, 
          36, 
          38, 
          39, 
          555, 
          556, 
          46, 
          68, 
          589, 
          597, 
          598, 
          599, 
          600, 
          92, 
          93, 
          95, 
          96, 
          97, 
          98, 
          99, 
          103, 
          104, 
          111, 
          625, 
          629, 
          630, 
          124, 
          126, 
          127, 
          128, 
          641, 
          130, 
          131, 
          133, 
          134, 
          136, 
          649, 
          138, 
          651, 
          533, 
          653, 
          142, 
          143, 
          144, 
          145, 
          150, 
          152, 
          665, 
          666, 
          623, 
          668, 
          538, 
          670, 
          671, 
          672, 
          673, 
          674, 
          163, 
          677, 
          173, 
          693, 
          694, 
          695, 
          696, 
          190, 
          704, 
          195, 
          196, 
          199, 
          206, 
          209, 
          222, 
          379, 
          743, 
          1280, 
          233, 
          234, 
          236, 
          752, 
          1272, 
          1273, 
          1274, 
          1275, 
          252, 
          1277, 
          766, 
          1279, 
          768, 
          1281, 
          258, 
          259, 
          260, 
          261, 
          774, 
          129, 
          1293, 
          270, 
          271, 
          272, 
          274, 
          787, 
          1301, 
          790, 
          791, 
          283, 
          1318, 
          809, 
          810, 
          811, 
          813, 
          814, 
          815, 
          306, 
          308, 
          309, 
          1336, 
          1338, 
          318, 
          1343, 
          321, 
          834, 
          139, 
          836, 
          838, 
          844, 
          845, 
          846, 
          141, 
          336, 
          739, 
          667, 
          1370, 
          350, 
          357, 
          358, 
          319, 
          882, 
          372, 
          885, 
          889, 
          890, 
          891, 
          380, 
          1258, 
          1412, 
          835, 
          1429, 
          1430, 
          1431, 
          744, 
          413, 
          414, 
          415, 
          1441, 
          1443, 
          422, 
          427, 
          255, 
          669, 
          446, 
          452, 
          453, 
          454, 
          455, 
          459, 
          460, 
          462, 
          463, 
          254, 
          249, 
          847, 
          1504, 
          1276, 
          491, 
          765, 
          1278, 
          503, 
          506, 
          767, 
          510
        )
  ) 
ORDER BY 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."is_instock" DESC NULLS LAST, 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."price" DESC NULLS LAST, 
  "products_amalgamateddisplayproduct"."orig_product_id" ASC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 
  51
```

Results in:

```
 Limit  (cost=24188.37..24188.88 rows=51 width=812) (actual time=13.965..14.054 rows=51 loops=1)
   ->  Unique  (cost=24188.37..24197.66 rows=929 width=812) (actual time=13.964..14.048 rows=51 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=24188.37..24190.69 rows=929 width=812) (actual time=13.963..13.972 rows=216 loops=1)
               Sort Key: is_instock DESC NULLS LAST, price DESC NULLS LAST, orig_product_id
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 692kB
               ->  Index Scan using products_adp_where_1 on products_amalgamateddisplayproduct  (cost=0.43..24142.57 rows=929 width=812) (actual time=0.073..6.212 rows=22
40 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((location_id = ANY ('{608,65,610,69,999,72,92,79,81,84,1045,89,601,954,603,1276,605,607}'::integer[])) AND (placement_id = ANY ('{512,1,
516,5,9,12,525,526,1042,21,22,23,26,517,34,35,36,38,39,555,556,46,68,589,597,598,599,600,92,93,95,96,97,98,99,103,104,111,625,629,630,124,126,127,128,641,130,131,133,134,
136,649,138,651,533,653,142,143,144,145,150,152,665,666,623,668,538,670,671,672,673,674,163,677,173,693,694,695,696,190,704,195,196,199,206,209,222,379,743,1280,233,234,2
36,752,1272,1273,1274,1275,252,1277,766,1279,768,1281,258,259,260,261,774,129,1293,270,271,272,274,787,1301,790,791,283,1318,809,810,811,813,814,815,306,308,309,1336,1338
,318,1343,321,834,139,836,838,844,845,846,141,336,739,667,1370,350,357,358,319,882,372,885,889,890,891,380,1258,1412,835,1429,1430,1431,744,413,414,415,1441,1443,422,427,
255,669,446,452,453,454,455,459,460,462,463,254,249,847,1504,1276,491,765,1278,503,506,767,510}'::integer[])))
                     Filter: (location_intspace = 755)
 Planning Time: 0.871 ms
 Execution Time: 14.158 ms
(10 rows)
```

Comment: Reindexing the table has no effect. The query planning still will use the ordered index (products_adp_order_2) instead of the where.

Comment: vacuum full and vacuum analyze also didn't help... Does anyone have any insight on how index selection is performed? MySQL and Oracle have FORCE INDEX and USE INDEX. Postgres community is against any hints to the planner but doesn't really give a ton of information on what criteria is used to determine index usage.

Comment: Look at the `cost` values - PostgreSQL calculates it wrongly. You need to tune some parameters according to your environment, in particular: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS

Comment: PS: You can set values of those parameters for session using `set <parameter> to <value>;` in your SQL tool. When you find the optimal combination - execute `alter system set <parameter> to <value>;` to store it permanently.

Comment: Very often joining to a values list is faster than an IN condition (assuming no duplicates), e.g `from t1 join ( values (1),(2),(3),... ) as x(id) on t1.id = x.id`

Comment: It doesn't look you disabled parallel workers, as one of the plans is parallel.

Comment: "Now another query where that second order by index is very useful"  That query is not actually using the index you say is useful for it.

Comment: Workers Launched: 0